# Make a Captions Page

Tags: latex, caption

I want to know if there is an easy way to extract the captions of one latex file with the numbers of the figures they are from.
For example if I have 3 figures in defined in my latex file, I need to create a document with the captions of those figures, e.g.,

```
Fig. 1. Caption of Fig. 1 
Fig. 2. Another caption
Fig. 3. Yet another caption
```

Is there any way of doing this using latex? or should I do it with other program?
I have several figures, so I don't want to go and extract the captions one by one, because I have to number them manually.

**Solution.**
I solve the problem with a work around. I use another file to include the list of figures and process them separately. The file that I included contains a modified list of figures as follows

```
{\renewcommand*\numberline[1]{Fig.\,#1:\space}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{\noindent#1\par}
\makeatother
\listoffigures}
```

Then, I include it in the original file with `\include` command. Then it creates the list of figures file as `file.lof`, I used that file to compile a minimal file to produce the list of figures separately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}       % This avoids problems with subfigures captions
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % I used math in my captions
\nofiles                     % This makes the aux and lof file not to be deleted
\begin{document}
\include{list}               % Includes the same file as before
\end{document}
```

I was using a different class, other than article, therefore, I need to copy some redefinitions in the auxiliar file. Rename the `file.lof` to this new file, so latex find it and it will do the work. I put all this in a script and now it works automatically.
Hth.

Comment: [TeX.StackExchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The `\listoffigures` control sequence may help you.

Comment: I need something similar. I need that list without page numbers and in another file. Is it possible?

Comment: @adn: Then I suggest to use a perl script

Comment: Take a look at the .lof file that is generated. It's easy to extract the information from there. (You could also re-define the command used there and \input{yourfile.lof})

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that file. I saw that the information is there. Is there any latex command to build the list of figures from that file automatically or should I do it with my own script?